# Allen Bradley L16ER communication via Python

Tags: python, communication, robotics, plc

I am trying to communicate with an Allen Bradley L16ER PLC via python. What I've found online says that I should use either CPPPO or pycomm modules to accomplish this. I have looked for a good source of documentation for these, and was unable to find one. Is there a good place to find an explanation of the basics of how to use either of these? Also, is there an alternative solution that may work better?

To further define my problem, let's define understanding of using this module into three layers.

1. Understanding Python.
2. Understanding how PLCs communicate.
3. Understanding how to use these modules.

While I understand level 1, I don't understand level 2. This makes it very hard to understand level 3.

Comment: https://github.com/ruscito/pycomm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look at pylogix, it has some example code for it:

https://github.com/dmroeder/pylogix